# Feeds module is stripping html tags from xml

Tags: importing-exporting, feeds

I tried my best to find an answer, but now I am finally stuck.

I am using Drupal 7.36, Feeds 7.x-2.0-alpha8 and used already 7.x-2.x-dev.

I am trying to **import a XML file** using the [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module with a simple structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <persons>
    <person>
      <number><p>12</p></number>
    </person>
    <person>
      <number><ul><li>2</li></ul></number>
    </person>
</persons>
```

But all I get after the import is the plain text 12 without any HTML tags.

I created a **custom Content type named Persons** and added one field to it, which accepts as text processing '**filtered text**'.

For this purpose I checked, that my **filtered text is accepting p, li and ul tags**. For that I edited all relevant text formats at:
admin/config/content/formats

Anyway, after for the purpose of solving this issue I do actually just use Full HTML now, without any restrictions. If I type in HTML **manually** into a Person content entity the **HTML tag stays there** properly.

In the **Feeds module** I added an importer and chose under **Processor** (in my case node processor) 'texte-format' Full HTML. Here I added as a bundle my Person content type.

As **parser** I use XPath XML parser.

**Fetcher** is File-Upload.

The importer is properly attached to Persons content type under basic settings.

Anyway, always, when I import my XML, it strips off the HTML tags.

I do not use any WYSIWYG module.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you switch to QueryPath XML parser (you need [Feeds extensible parsers](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds_ex) and [QueryPath](https://www.drupal.org/project/querypath)) which supports RAW input which should solve your issue.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my day. Indeed the combination of **the two plugins solve this issue**. To just get the HTML tags, you just need to check 'raw' and 'inner XML'. After that, importing html in xml tags works perfectly smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I appears to me that the issue you are trying to resolve, might be related to the issue described in [issue # 2224643](https://www.drupal.org/node/2224643) (on D.O).

If that's the case, then you might want to try the [commit mentioned in #22 in that issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2224643#comment-8965133) (or the patch attached to #20 there).

Comment: Hi Pierre, thanks for your advice. Unfortunately it is **not solving** the problem. After installing the patches and choosing the per field format rightly to full HTML or any other HTML, which allows the proper tags, the tags **still got chopped off**. This is really strange, maybe the problem starts already, when the XML file is read and handed to feeds? I am really out of ideas ...